# Working with "action sequence" data. i.e. vectors with varying lengths for each person

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I have to work with some (for me) unusual data for my student job. My boss sent me a script with the following "minimal example" of the data set I'm supposed to work with. ActSeqList stands for action sequence list and there is one for every person. The actions can't be condensed into a dataframe because different persons have varying numbers of actions. "a", "b" etc.. stand for which action was executed. The DurRTList contains the reaction times pertaining to the actions executed by each person. 
Thus each person has an ActSeqList and a corresponding DurRTList. Now my instruction are:

1- determine for each action the proportion of persons to have executed that action at least once.

2- create a vector for each action that contains all the reaction times associated with that action.

3- (this step is probably easier once the others are done) compute the median reaction time for each action.

Now, I don't expect (or want) anyone to write code for me I'm just hoping someone could point me to some packages or functions I could start with as swirl certainly did not prepare me for this and I have no clue how to start.

Many thanks in advance! :)

```r
ActSeqList<-list()
ActSeqList[[1]]<-c("a","b","c")
ActSeqList[[2]]<-c("b","a","c","d")
ActSeqList[[3]]<-c("a","d","e","f","d")

DurRTList<-list()
DurRTList[[1]]<-c(156,40,210)
DurRTList[[2]]<-c(41,320,27,560)
DurRTList[[3]]<-c(27,99,123,710,79)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: For starters, what you've described can be represented by a data frame with the data in a long format. Having the data in this format will make it easier to work with and help with your next steps.

Comment: To get you started: `df <- data.frame(id = rep(sequence(length(ActSeqList)), lengths(ActSeqList)), action = unlist(ActSeqList), duration = unlist(DurRTList))`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm unfortunately not managing to find away to work my way through 1 and 2 :(

Comment: For 1 you can do something like `colMeans(table(df[1:2]) > 0)`.  For 2, you might find the `split()` function helpful.